# Laravel passing array to view

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to pass my array to my view but it shows me the error

> Undefined variable: arr (View: /var/www/resources/views/test.blade.php)

I already looked through a few Stackoverflow entries but I didn't find anything that helped. I am using Laravel version 5.8.38

Controller(i know it isn't some beautiful code and it's outdated but i was trying something):

```
public function getData() {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";


        $servername = "laradock_mysql_1";
        $username = "default";
        $password = "secret";
        $dbname = "default";
        $conn = new \mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        $counter = 0;
        $arr[] = null;
        while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            // echo("<div".$zeile['id']."</div>");
            if ($counter == 0) {
                $arr[0] = $zeile;
            } else {
                $arr[] = $zeile;
            }
            $counter++;
        }
        
        return view('test', compact("arr"));
    }
```

View:

```
<body>
    @foreach($arr as $item)
    <div>
        {{ $item }}
    </div>
    @endforeach   
    
</body>
```

I also made a route and returned just the Array (with a dd($arr)) right before the return, and it shows the data i want to transmit

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => "1"
    "titel" => "Test"
    "subtitel" => "1"
    "price" => "9.6"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => "2"
    "titel" => "Test 2"
    "subtitel" => "2"
    "price" => "9.4"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => "3"
    "titel" => "Test 3"
    "subtitel" => "3"
    "price" => "9.88"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Not related, but you might want to take a look at [Laravel Database](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database), [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) and [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent). No need to use `new \mysqli`, `mysqli_query` or `mysqli_fetch_array` in Laravel

Comment: Why are you not using Laravel specific database tools? instead of this outdated aproach? this code is not at all close to best practice in laravel, please read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database

Comment: thank you but how i said, i just wanted to try something

Comment: Does `$arr` contain data? Use `dd($arr);` before you return the view

Comment: i'm sorry but i am still new to laravel, what should happen if i write the dd?

Comment: [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-dd) it is a cleaner way and cleaner data presentdation of var_dump and die.

Comment: ah ok, yes it contains data

Comment: have you checked if correct controller method is being called? Because it should work.

Comment: what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know from the comments this code isn't great.

That being said, the problem does not seem related to how you're passing the array to your view.
If you add

```
$arr=[1,2];
```

just before the redirect it should show "1","2" just fine in your view.

You should probably debug a little with

```
dd($arr);
```

in several places in your code to make sure the array is actually getting the values you're expecting from the database.

Comment: well i tried it with a new array, just with 2 numbers, as you mentioned and it did still not work and shows me the same error

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: i am currently using version 5.8.38

Comment: Strange , do you get the array with the valuesif you put `dd(compact("arr"));` just before  `return view('test', compact("arr"));`?

Comment: yes, i get the values, i already edited it into the question